# create JQuery object from raw xml in explorer

Tags: jquery, xml, internet-explorer, xml-parsing

I have a script that accepts XML input, and I want to convert it to JQuery object so that I can traverse it easily.

This is the code I use:

```
var xmlInput = 
'<content>'+
    '<action xsi:type="number">'+
    "123"+
    '</action>'+
'</content>';
var object = $(xmlInput);
alert(object);
alert(object.html());
object.find("action").each(function() {
    var type = $(this).attr("xsi:type");
    alert("action! type="+type);
});
```

(available online here:
http://irsrv2.cs.biu.ac.il:8080/GeniusWeb/jqueryTest.html )

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome:

- the first alert shows "object",
- the second alert shows the inner "action" element,
- and a third alert shows "action! type=number".

However, in MSIE 8, this apparently doesn't work :

- the first alert shows "object",
- the second alert shows an empty string.
- and there is no third alert.

What should I do to make the code work in IE 8 too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it an xml document rather than an HTML fragment with invalid html ( which IE correctly chokes on )

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xmlstring);

$(xmlDoc).doSomething()
```